Can transceivers count to fifty resonators?
I asked a since-closed question yesterday about an alternative to RFID. I assumed the way to phrase the question was as the most general possible engineering problem. I infer that it is probably better to explain my hunch.
The problem is cheap short range wireless ID with a use case for a game that means one doesn’t have to worry about spoofing of any kind.
My hunch is that you can do it with off the shelf components and cheap to manufacture resonators. My guess at a general recipe is the following.

Take an antenna of sufficiently short wavelength that a resonator of some kind can fit in a centimetre cube. Such a resonator should be able to produce a nice clear signal in the transceiver a few centimetres away.

My worry is that mm band is expensive, and anything longer-wave would need too big a resonator. Perhaps I am pessimistic here, but this is where I show my ignorance most. The ideal would be if there was a canonical design for a resonator with this purpose at low frequency- certainly my search has not found anything.
And then there’s the discrimination problem (the ‘counting to fifty’ in the title). Let’s say I can have as many of these centimetre cube resonators as I like, my core question is how (if at all) I can get 6-7 bits out?
One way of getting bits would be with distinct resonators, but it’s not clear to me how many distinct resonators could you fit in the frequency band where resonators are below my required size.
I would prefer not to have to think about this! Or maybe I am being pessimistic again, but lots of precision spec resonators sound expensive.
My preferred solution for the purposes of production would be if the transceiver were able to count the number of resonators at a given frequency (up to about fifty), but again, I’m failing at the order of magnitude step, not being acquainted with the hardware.
So in ascending order of difficulty:

Can a cheap transceiver count to 1 cheap resonator?
Can it count fifty or so of them?
And is making resonators of differing frequencies much easier than I imagine?


You haven't stated the problem you're trying to solve. All you have is a vague description of a candidate solution that you obviously don't understand. There is no way for us to tell if such a solution could solve an unstated problem.

Is this for a game of some sort?

It is for a game! And @JohnDoty I will try and state the problem clearly again in an edit. Sorry- my last attempt was accused of only stating the problem!

@JohnDoty how’s that? Any better?

your last post was flagged as a shopping questions ... please edit that question, instead of posting this one

@jsotola I deleted that one- sorry if this is bad form, but I have to go to bed. I would appreciate it if you didn’t close this one on those grounds.

@TomBoardman I do not have the power to close your question ... it takes three votes to close a question
